# ajax calendar not displaying in child gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Ajax Calendar not displaying in child GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVCollapse" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  OnClick="Show_Hide_ChildGrid" ImageUrl="~/images/plus.png" CommandArgument="Show" Height="20" Width="20" />  
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server">     
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dispatch Date">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:TextBox Width="90px" ID="txtDispatchDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                                 <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                    PopupButtonID="txtDispatchDate" TargetControlID="txtDispatchDate">
                                 </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>        
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Ajax Calendar is not working in child gridview whereas I did the same thing with parent gridview then it's working well
is Ajax calendar not working with child gridview?? or I did any mistake. I posted my design code

Comment: This's too broad and I believe, you have **JavaScript/jQuery** issue in the code.

Comment: do you have a script component at the top of the page?